# C++ Program crashing when default copy constructor is called

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, copy-constructor

I'm writing a map class that reads information from XML documents and builds a map object. The map first reads the tile type definitions from a XML file and stores it in a map, indexing each tile's information by its ID. After that it reads another file with the information of the map landscape (tile coordinates, etc) and attempts to fill in a tile array.

It's something like this:

```
class TileInfo {
    //Information about tile stats, bitmaps, movement cost etc
};

class Tile {
     TileInfo* info;
     vector<TileInfo*> lastSeenByPlayer; //due to fow each player can be seeing different tiles since they haven't updated yet
     //other tile specific tile information like coordinates etc
public:
     Tile(int x, int y, TileInfo* info /*other parameters*/);
};

Tile::Tile(int x, int y, TileInfo* info /*...*/) {
     this->info = tileInfo;
     this->x = x;
     this->y = y;

     for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++)
          lastSeenByPlayer.push_back(info);
}

class GameMap {
     map<int,TileInfo> tileInformation;
     vector<vector<Tile>> tiles;

     Tile loadTile(int tileID, int x, int y);
     void loadTerrainFromFile(string filename);
};

Tile GameMap::loadTile(int tileID, int x, int y) {
     map<int,TileInfo>::iterator it = tileInformation.find(tileID);
     if( it!=tileInformation.end())
         TileInfo* info = &(it->second);
     else
         throw errorLoadingTile();

    return Tile(x,y,info /*other information*/);
}

void GameMap::loadTerrainFromFile(string filename) {
     //open file and read information
     //at this point the GameMap already has the map with the tile information filled
     //from when it was created

     for(unsigned int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
         for(unsigned int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
              cout << "Works up to here" << endl;
              tiles[y][x] = loadTile(tileIDs[x][y],x,y);
              cout << "Crashes before this" << endl;

         }

    //do more stuff
};
```

I think it's something to do with the copy constructor but Tile doesn't have a destructor that deletes anything so it can't be deleting the TileInfo*, that's the maps' responsibility. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try debugging the problem. The debugger should stop at the place of the crash. Then post results.

Comment: Does it actualy compile? In 'GameMap::loadTile' you have `TileInfo* info = ` assigned in if, maybe you are passing to ` return Tile(x,y,info /*other information*/);` some other null info?

Comment: I figured it out guys. I'm retarded -.- ,  I changed the tiles to a vector of vectors and forgot to change the assignment to a push_back. Thanks for the answers, and I'll change the TileInfo* info declaration to not be on the if.

Comment: @user2302419: ok, maybe you want to write your own answer and accept it so that people no longer read your question and try to solve your problem.